# What is the alternative of document.getElementById("filedata"); in jquery?.

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var fileproperty=document.getElementById("file_data");
```

I want to get the property of the file_data through jquery.

Comment: `$("#file_data");`

Comment: This is really the kind of simple question that you should be capable of researching for yourself. A google search would have lead you to http://learn.jquery.com, specifically, [How to Select an Element](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/)

Answer (score 1):

You would just use:

```
$('#file_data');
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#file_data');

Jquery works same as CSS selectors, basically. So if you select an ID, you prefix it with #, if you are trying to select a class, you prefix it with '.'
It, obviously, enables more advanced tree traversal, but basically, elements are selected in the same way as with CSS